# connecting strings

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my code for connecting different NSNumbers from an array to one string. But for some reason I get a weird result in the watch area. The result of the NSLog is fine. Maybe you can help?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ViewController sharedInstance].safeZonesUserList.count; i++) {
    int userIndex = [[[ViewController sharedInstance].safeZonesUserList objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    NSString *arrayValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",userIndex];
    usersList = [usersList stringByAppendingString:arrayValue];
    if (i < ([ViewController sharedInstance].safeZonesUserList.count - 1)) {
        usersList = [usersList stringByAppendingString:@","];
    }
}
```

My array holds 1 and 2, but the result I get in the watch area is: "1,2;\x8c\a@\x01\x03206"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your example with one line of code:

```
NSString* usersListAsString = [[ViewController sharedInstance].safeZonesUserList componentsJoinedByString:@","] ;
```

`componentsJoinedByString` gets the `description`s of every item in your NSArray, replacing the first 2 lines of code within your loop. Then it combines the `description`s into one NSString with your specified string (",") in-between them, replacing your example's lines 3 - 5.